# What side of the door was Seth on when he pushed the rocking horse down the stairs?

Tags: fablehaven

In book 3 of Fablehaven after

> the brownies set up traps in the house

Seth pushes a rocking horse down the stairs. After that he tells Kendra that it was awesome. The passage has confused me a lot and I would like to know what side of the door he was on? I always thought he was on the side of the stairs.

Comment: @Edlothiad ninja'd me with that edit

Comment: @Gallifreyan, learning from the best :P

Comment: Wow didn't notice I left out the rocking part. I can imagine a horse going down those stairs :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read this a few more times and he was inside the attic. He said to Kendra "That was awesome" before the door was opened. Also he "rolled out of the way" and if he was outside the door that would have not worked. So therefore he was inside.